# Elasticsearch running aggregate guery - products bought by clients who only buy that product

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, nosql, kibana

My docs represents an order in the given format:

```
{
   "name", // the client
   "sku"   // the product
}
```

So, suppose the follow data exists:

```
{   "name": "rudolph",  "sku": "apple" }
{   "name": "rudolph",  "sku": "apple" }
{   "name": "rudolph",  "sku": "apple" }
{   "name": "john",     "sku": "banana" }
{   "name": "john",     "sku": "banana" }
{   "name": "paul",     "sku": "banana" }
{   "name": "paul",     "sku": "apple" }
{   "name": "peter",    "sku": "banana" }
```

I can get the clients who bought only 1 kind of item with the query:

```
{
"aggs": {
    "clients": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "name"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "distinct_sku": {
                "cardinality": {
                    "field": "sku"
                }
            },
            "unique_sku": {
                "bucket_selector": {
                    "buckets_path": {
                        "qty": "distinct_sku"
                    },
                    "script": "params.qty == 1"
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "sku"
              }
            }
        }
    }
},
"size": 0
}
```

which results

```
{   
...
"aggregations": {
    "clients": {
      ...
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "rudolph",
          "doc_count": 3,
          ...
          "aggs": {
            ...
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "apple",
                "doc_count": 3
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "john",
          "doc_count": 2,
          ...
          "aggs": {
            ...
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "banana",
                "doc_count": 2
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "peter",
          "doc_count": 1,
          ...
          "aggs": {
            ...
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "banana",
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
}
}
```

It's possible to manage the query to return how much each item appears in the result?

Something like this:
{
    "apple" : 1,
    "banana" : 2 
}

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
My base has a huge amount of clients and a small quantity of products, so:

1. Iterate over the above aggregation result to build the wanted result is not an option.
2. If I have to send a query for each product, It's Ok.

Comment: Isn't that what "buckets" is showing? The "key" is your "banana" and the "doc_count" is your 2. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: No, this is which item and the amount each consumer has bought. I whant this: {"apple": 1 client bought this, "banana": 2 clients bought this }